# How To Make A check In Php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code,i want to check against empid if cli and callduration both are same and evaluated before it..then show this cli and call duration is already evaluated..if cli is same but duration is different then show start evaluation and also if cli and duration both are different then also show start evaluation.

The problem which i am facing is that my code is only check one statement like empid=1,cli=123,calldurations is 1min &01:01 then its check only 1 min duration and on 01:01 duration print the statement start evaluation..the code should show call is already evaluated..

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usman");
$check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eval WHERE empid = '$_POST[empid]' &&  cli =  '$_POST[cli]'  && callduration = '$_POST[callduration]' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$check);
$count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(current($count) > 0) {
  echo "<tr><td>This call is already evaluated against </td></tr><tr><td> Emp-ID " . $_POST["empid"] . "</td></tr><tr><td>CLI - " . $_POST["cli"] . "</td></tr><tr><td>Call Duration - " . $_POST["callduration"] . "</td></tr>";
}
else
{
  echo "<a href='evaluationsheet.php?empid= ". $_GET["empid"] ." && agentname= ". $_GET["agentname"] ." && doj= ". $_GET["doj"] ." && department= ". $_GET["department"] ." && division= ". $_GET["division"] ." && designation= ". $_GET["designation"] ." && image= ". $_GET["image"] ." && cli= ". $_POST["cli"] ." && callduration= ". $_POST["callduration"] ."  '> Click Here To Start Evaluation </h1>";

}
?>
```

Comment: I see the word "eval" and no prepared statements; that sounds scary. I hope this isn't a live or going live site.

Comment: You have an SQL Injection vulnerability, so first off rewrite to use a prepared statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @AlexK. how can i fix this issue???

Comment: @AlexK. the link u enter did not helpful for me

Comment: I disagree, it is _very_ helpful. It will prevent your system from falling to automated scripts and malicious users. Something which _will_ cause you to lose all control of your site, have all of your user's details (including e-mail address, and the password they also use for it), having your server used as a spam-bot and everything else you most assuredly don't want to happen.

Comment: It'll also help make your code a lot easier to read, and thus understand. Which, frankly neither your question or code is at the moment. Which explains why people are reluctant to help you, as it requires a lot more effort to help than it seems you've put into actually asking the question. (After all, if you can't be bothered to take your time, why should we..?) Just a friendly tip. :)

Comment: Are you sending a `POST` request? `<a href='evaluationsheet.php?empid= ` suggests you are sending a `GET`. You also shouldn't have the spaces between the value and parameter and the double ampersand is strange.

Comment: @- chris85 thanks chris